# How to use SQL with dates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following `WHERE` condition:

```
order_date between date_add(
                      CAST(concat( YEAR(current_timestamp()), '-',
                                  MONTH(current_timestamp()), '-',
                                  DAY(current_timestamp()),' ',
                                  hour(current_timestamp())) as datetime) ,interval -1 hour) 

                      and
                      CAST(concat( YEAR(current_timestamp()), '-',
                                   MONTH(current_timestamp()), '-',
                                   DAY(current_timestamp()), ' ',
                                   hour(current_timestamp())) as datetime)
```

This condition works well on MySQL but it doesn't work on BigQuery.
It gives:

```
Error: Function not found: YEAR
```

I don't understand this error as `YEAR` is `SQL standard` - BigQuery does support it.

What is the problem here? (I'm looking for SQL standard solution)

I imagine that there are also better ways to achieve this condition so any suggestion for improvement is welcome.

**Example:**
The calculation takes `current_timestamp()` and calculates 1 hour earlier so:

if `current_timestamp() = 2018-12-17 11:42:52`
it gives:

```
Between `2018-12-17 10:00:00`  and `2018-12-17 11:00:00`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order_date >= datetime_add(datetime_trunc(current_datetime, hour), interval 1 hour) and
order_date < datetime_trunc(current_datetime, hour)
```

For the record, `year()` is not standard SQL -- although it is available in many databases.  The standard function is `extract()`:  `extract(year from <val>)`.

Comment: Error: No matching signature for function DATETIME_TRUNC for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART) at [1:24]

Comment: @Luis . . . There are no timestamps in this answer.  This works fine in BigQuery:  `datetime_add(datetime_trunc(current_datetime, hour), interval 1 hour)`.